# Windows 7 IP conflict detected with VirtualBox host-only network

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, docker

I have Docker VirtualBox-based VM running on my PC with host only interface sitting on 192.168.99.1. I need it to be accessible only from host and do not want any visibility from outside. Sometimes I receive notifications about 192.186.99.1 IP conflict (based on events log message). Probably this is from other computers who have similar configuration as Docker IP assignment is static.

How can I avoid this annoying behaviour?

What I have tried:

- Disabling traffic from 192.168/16 network in firewall. It works but looks like it filters on too late stage - IP conflicts are still reported. Not a solution.
- Migrating interface on other private IP address. Docker infrastructure creates other host-only interface 192.168.99.1 and switches to it. Solution which requires periodic manual support. Not good.

Any other idea how to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I have found later the reason of conflict happened to be DHCP server and host-only network gateway interface assigned to the same IP interface. This was causing periodic internal conflict detection provoking Windows networking stack to behave pretty strange.

More recent Docker versions have corrected this issue. I see it is not present starting from `Docker toolbox 1.9.0c`. So solution happened just to upgrade.